# Appropriate Timing for Follow-Up After Positive Initial Response from Prospective Postdoc Advisor (Math)

Tags: mathematics, application, postdocs

I am a final year Ph.D. student in a US math department and I am in the process of applying for Postdoc positions.

After applying for a Postdoc position at a top 40 school, I emailed a professor I am really interested in working with. He replied saying that he would be interested in having me in the department and that he is hopeful that I will receive an offer soon.

I haven't heard from the school or the professor for 3 weeks now. I know this is extremely early but I am really anxious and I was wondering if it would be okay to contact the professor again. While I'm anxious, I don't want to be disrespectful or pushy. This is a person I truly admire for his work in academia and I would love the opportunity to work with him.

Comment: @Sursula I think my situation is a bit different because I haven't had any formal interviews or anything like that, but it definitely helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three weeks is fine. Ask if there are any updates and ask if they would like any additional information from you. Re-express your interest.

The timing seems quite good to me.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been a very nervous wait. Hopefully, I will get a positive response.